# Why is like-operator so fast

Tags: sql, database, algorithm, sql-like

you all know the like operator in sql. For example:

```
select * 
from customer 
where email like '%goog%'
```

So my question is how can the database return so fast a result?
When I should program a function like this, I would loop over all customers and over each email. But this is very slow. I heard about indexes. How can a database use a index when the database doesn't know which the first or last letter is? Or is their a other way to do it?

I don't want to program something like this. I only want to know how it works.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? This will usually be pretty slow in MySQL, I don't know how other databases do it.

Comment: DB server would not be able to efficiently use index here, so it'll have to use full index scan (assuming `email` is indexed). Still, full index scan is very much faster than full table scan.

Comment: It also depends on the contents. Even table scans may perform very well if you don't have complex queries and only a couple of hundreds of rows as the DBMS may just perform everything in memory. It just won't scale.

Comment: Can you provide a short benchmark showing it is indeed so fast when the beginning of the query is also a wild card compared to where the wild card is in the middle/end of the query? I know many SQL engines run [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) under the hood for such things, but [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) does not support first character as a wild card if I remember correctly.

Comment: Modern machines are fast. Really fast. Even without any indexes and no way to optimize it, even a commodity processor can easily scan 10.000 rows for a substring without breaking a sweat, and database engines have been optimized to make use of bulk I/O reads, caching  and multiple processors where available. Try it on a table with 10 million rows and see if it's still "so fast".

Comment: 'fast'? This is arguably *very* slow.

Comment: @RemusRusanu: oh, it **is** fast compared to doing the same in php or whatever :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what engine you are using and what's beneath its actual hood but here is some helpful information regarding this problem:

1. Often, SQL engines uses free text search inside the column to be able to extract queries like that extra fast. This is done by creating an [**inverted index**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index), that maps from each word to the "documents" (row,column) that contains them. One widely used library is [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/). Unfortunately, most IR (Information Retrieval) libraries do NOT support wild card at the beginning of the query (but they do for anywhere else), so your specific example cannot be searched in such index.
2. You can create an index to support a wild card at the beginning of the index, by using a [Suffix Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree). Suffix trees are excellent for searching a substring, like your example. However, they are not very optimized for searching a string with a wild card in the middle of it.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it this style of query is not very efficient - if there is a wild card that affects the start of words an entire scan is needed. However if the column is indexed the DBMS only has to bring the entire index into memory and scan it not the entire contents of the table - typically this would be a relatively fast task.

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know which RDBMS you're working with, let's look at one way that a database *could* benefit from an index in this sort of situation - and let's explore it via the book/index metaphor:

Imaging that each row of data takes up a page of a book, and on each page there'll be an email address. And at the end of the book, there's an index of email addresses - for each email address, it tells you which pages contain that email address. Each page of this index just contains email addresses and page numbers. Say that there's 50 email addresses per page.

If you want to find all the pages where the email address contain the letters `goog`, despite not knowing what the first or last letter of the email address is, do you think it will be easier for you to a) look through every page in the entire book, or b) scan down the email index at the back of the book taking note of which pages are useful (and then going to those pages if you need more information)?